# JQuery WildCard replace URL

Tags: jquery

I need to replace this URL

http:///prod/ap4s/appleproducts/iphone/4S

with

http:///prods.aspx?prod_id=ap4s

Taking productId "ap4s" from existing url and passing it as querystring.

```
('a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href')    <--- Modify href here.. 
}
```

I dont see replace to be of much help here. so looking for some better alternative or some suggestions to go ahead in right direction...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href','http:///prods.aspx?prod_id='+$(this).attr('href').split('/')[3]) 
}
```

Comment: hey Royi, Thanks for answer. Only correction here. to set a JQuery attribute, we need to use $(this).attr(old, new). We cannot set it like $(this).attr(old) = new; :). Thanks again.

Comment: I faced another issue here, index as you have provided works differently in IE and in Chrome. It seems IE starts with 0 and chrome with 1. I am still trying to further validate this, seems like a wierd issue. But, I may have to try some different solution. :(